# didReceiveIncomingPushWith - not working - iOS

Tags: ios, voip, quickblox, pushkit

I have implemented VOIP in swift.
Earlier it was working fine.
But, Now it is not triggering the `didReceiveIncomingPushWith` function.

Please find my configuration

```
let config = CXProviderConfiguration.init(localizedName: "AppName")
var provider: CXProvider!



 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   provider = CXProvider(configuration: config)
   provider.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
   self.registerVOIP()
}


 func registerVOIP()  {

        //register for voip notifications
        pushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
         pushRegistry.delegate = self;
        pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = Set([PKPushType.voIP])

    }

extension AppDelegate : PKPushRegistryDelegate{
    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {

    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {


        }
   }
```

In the extension method, `didUpdate` works fine, since delegate is set in didiFinishLoad

I am using QuickBlox for VOIP
I check the voip certificate everything is fine.

Here the quick box new session delegate

```
extension AppDelegate : QBRTCClientDelegate{

    func didReceiveNewSession(_ session: QBRTCSession, userInfo: [String : String]? = nil) {
        print(#function)

    }
}

the didReceiveNewSession  function is trigger when receives a new call (If the app is in foreground)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, it is Quickblox server-side code needs to be changed.